# use variable values as parameters in stage script in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I seems that my variable values not enterpret when using them as paramters in a stage-script

I have a Jenkins pipeline that starets a sas program with parameters from a script block. I am setting my values in top of the file, i have verified that i can echo the values out

With a stage like this

```
stage("test parametre"){
  steps{
    script{
      echo "This is bank_param: ${bank_param}"
      echo "This is banks: ${banks}"
      echo "This is saspath: ${saspath}"
      echo "This is sasmbit: ${sasnbit}"
      echo "This is env: ${env}"
      echo "This is layer:${layer}"
      echo "This is lognbit: ${lognbit}"
      echo "This is samlet: ${saspath} -sysin ${sasnbit} -set env ${env} -set layer ${layer} -set banks \"${bank_param}\" -log ${lognbit}" 
    }
  } 
}
```

But then i try to use those values as parameters in the  stage("Build test") they are not recongnized as variables.

```
def env ="T"
def layer = "SS"
def bank_param = "333,332,333,334"
def banks = bank_param.split(',')
def saspath = "C:\\Progra~1\\SAS94\\SASFoundation\\9.4\\sas.exe"
           
def nunitpath = "bin\\nbi\\nunit\\bin\\nunit-console.exe"
def sasnbit = "src\\macros\\CREATE_NBITS_BANKNR_ENV.sas"
def lognbit = "log\\nbi\\BUILD_NBI_TEST.log"

pipeline {

 agent {
    label 'Deploymentserver'
}

   
stages {
    

    stage("Build test"){
        steps{
            script{
                bat(script: "${saspath} -sysin ${sasnbit} -set env ${env} -set layer ${layer} -set banks \"${bank_param}\" -log ${lognbit}", returnStatus: true, returnStdout: true) 
                findText regexp: '^(ERROR:)(?!.*(?i)page)', fileSet:'log/nbi/*.log' , alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true , unstableIfFound: true
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

}

Usually i used to get the values from Jenkins configuration as

```
def env = params.ENVIRONMENT
def layer = params.LAYER
def bank_param = params.BANKS
def banks = params.BANKS.split(',')
```

and that worked.
But not when i define them directly in the jenkinsfile

Comment: Could you include the output (error text) of the job?

Comment: the errors is not produced by the pipeline, but by the sas program i try to start because it doent get the parameters example: [Text Finder] Searching console output...
[Text Finder] Finished searching for pattern '^(ERROR:)(?!.*(?i)page)' in console output.
[Text Finder] Searching for pattern '^(ERROR:)(?!.*(?i)page)' in file set 'log/nbi/*.log'...
K:\Jenkins\Workspaces\Data\workspace\DAT_datatest_landingzone_develop\log\nbi\BUILD_NBI_TEST.log:
ERROR:Input bank is incorrect
ERROR:The macro ended abnormally

Comment: Which part is not working? Is it not calling the SAS program?  Are the three environment variables you are trying to define by using the `-set` option not set properly? Why not just set the environment variables before calling the SAS program instead of trying to use the `-set` option?

Comment: It is how SAS programs running in batch is reading parameters, the problem is that the variables seems to be empty in the statement

Comment: Try to define your variables as environment variables in environment block of the pipeline. `environment { env = "T" layer = "SS" ...}`.